# How to change the color of a switch in different android versions?

Tags: android, xml

My current toggle switch is working on my android device with 'Jelly Bean', the thumb is changing its color when it's enabled or disabled.
On a different android device with 'Lollipop' the switch is looking different by default and if I try to change the color of the thumb the whole switch gets invisible.

I need a solution for both versions where the thumb of the switch will change its color depending on its state.

My switch:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/swManual"
    android:thumb="@drawable/swManual"/>
```

My drawable for the thumb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/swOff"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/swOn"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: You can place different files in the `res/values-vXX` where the `XX` is the API numbers for Lollipop and JellyBean

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using the [SwitchCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) library, which is part of the design support library.  It emulates the latest switch components, and will change color based on `colorPrimary` and `android:colorPrimary` attributes in your styles.xml.